# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet - return a matching record from the search query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to return a distinct record from the database based on the search query. This is my attempt

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(String employeeName) { 
        String query = "SELECT e. FROM Employees e WHERE e.name like '%"+ employeeName +"%'";
        List<Object[]> employeeObjects = hibernateUtil.fetchAll(query);
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        for(Object[] employeeObject: employeeObjects) {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            long id = ((BigInteger) employeeObject[0]).longValue();         
            int age = (int) employeeObject[1];
            String name = (String) employeeObject[2];
            float salary = (float) employeeObject[3];
            employee.setId(id);
            employee.setName(name);
            employee.setAge(age);
            employee.setSalary(salary);
            employees.add(employee);
        }
        System.out.println(employees);
        return employees;
    }
```

On the above attempt, I have this error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Employees e WHERE e.name like '%john%'' at line 1
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

please how do i modify my query to select a unique record

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT e. FROM Employees e WHERE e.name like " => there is an **dot(.)** after SELECT e. It should be SELECT DISTINCT e.name FROM Employees ....